# Injecting topic to @KafkaListener annotation from another config class

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a java config class say like this

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Value("${kafka.topic:default_topic}")
    String kafkaTopic;
}
```

And my current KafkaListener has an annotation like this

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}")
    public void processMe(@Payload  String  msg) {
```

I want to use the getter method from my config class and inject the topic to the KafkaListener.  The KafkaListener is in its own class

How is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can access is using [spring expression language](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language#6-accessing-list-and-map-objects)

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{myConfig.getKafkaTopic()}")
public void processMe(@Payload  String  msg) {
```

Comment: Thank you, just found it the hard way by doing more reading and your reply is correct. I use lombok and I was also using the wrong getter name so decompiled the generated class and yes it works.